# SQL Server compare design method

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a project that have a big database, i want to know that which design is better, one database with 5 table or 5 database with 1 table?
My database is run on the server, if i want to extend my db to more than one server , is it change in answer that question?

Comment: I always vote for fewer database - within a **single** database, you can set up referential integrity using foreign key constraints; that doesn't work across database boundaries.... it also seems a lot easier to access and manage **one database** with five tables - instead of having five separate databases....

Comment: @marc, I gotta agree with you there. Complicating the deployment would generally be the last line of defense concerning database performance. Generally databases don't perform well, in my experience, because they aren't indexed properly or the server literally doesn't have enough horsepower to manage the load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general prescription a database isn't going to perform better just because it only has one table. Further, the concept of sharding and it's performance enhancements (or not) are way too far reaching for this forum.

So, to make your life easier, make one database with five tables, and optimize those tables properly. Build indexes where they are necessary based on how you query the database. Build covered indexes where possible. And don't over index if the application is write intensive.

Remember, optimizing a database is much more involved than a general design pattern and cannot be done well by an outside source without an excessive amount of information.

Comment: thanks, could i have more than one server with one database?(for speed up my query)

Comment: @Mahyar, you're still trying to complicate the deployment without yet understanding if there will be or **even are** any performance issues that can be resolved like that. In short, what you just proposed was something that would require Replication between two SQL servers and there are a *lot* of complexities involved with that. ***Build one database, on one server, and when it's live troubleshoot the performance issues. Likely every issue can be resolved without complicating the deployment.***